# android.view.InflateException with dynamic setText from Custom view

Tags: android, xml, inflate-exception

I have a custom view "BallHoldView" which is run from an activity "BallHoldActivity" by adding said view to the BallHoldActivity layout resource within merge tags. Also within the same layout xml is a TextView (scoreText). I want to set scoreText's text dynamically from the BallHoldView.
When my program tries to run scoreText.setText("new text here"); I get a view.InflateException. Commenting out this one line of code removes the errors.

Through online research I have identified the following:

- my BallHoldView needs a constructor with Attributes passed to it. (Check)
- my scoreText needs to be instantiated with reference to the activity, not the view: ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.scoreText); (Check)
- It seems the majority of issues with this exception is that something is not declared properly in the xml file. I think the problem is that I'm missing something in the xml file, but I don't know what, and I can't find a solution online.

Can anyone see what I'm missing, or what I've done wrong?

Main errors seem to be:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

xml line #12 (& #13):

```
<oaa.tms.zoneball.ballHold.BallHoldView
android:id="@+id/ballHold"
```

Null Pointer is at BallHoldView.java:37 which is:

```
scoreText.setText("New Score"); // java line 37.
```

Here's BallHoldView:

```
public class BallHoldView extends View
{
private ShapeDrawable circle10, circle50, circleEYE;
private TextView scoreText;
private int viewWidth, viewHeight;
private float circCentreX, circCentreY, circ10Radius, circ50Radius, circEyeRadius;

public BallHoldView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public BallHoldView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{ super(context, attrs);
 Log.e("BallHoldView", "CONSTRUCTOR ENTERED");
 circle10 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    circle10.getPaint().setColor(0xffff9900);
 circle50 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    circle50.getPaint().setColor(0xffb80000);
 circleEYE = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    circleEYE.getPaint().setColor(0xff000000);
 scoreText = (TextView)((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
            Log.e("BallHoldView", "scoreText created");
    scoreText.setText("New Score");
            Log.e("BallHoldView", "scoreText changed");
}

public void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    super.onDraw(c);
    // Draw some circles here
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)
{
    // change circle parameters here
}
}
```

Here's the xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_black_border"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="oaa.tms.zoneball.BallHoldActivity" >

<oaa.tms.zoneball.ballHold.BallHoldView
android:id="@+id/ballHold"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/scoreText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|left"
android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_textbg"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:text="@string/score" />

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/timeText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|right"
android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_textbg"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:text="@string/time" />

</merge>
```

Here's the log cat (errors):

```
10-05 17:44:04.326: E/BallHoldView(3474): CONSTRUCTOR ENTERED
10-05 17:44:04.326: E/BallHoldView(3474): scoreText created
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{oaa.tms.zoneball/oaa.tms.zoneball.BallHoldActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class oaa.tms.zoneball.ballHold.BallHoldView
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class oaa.tms.zoneball.ballHold.BallHoldView
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:460)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at oaa.tms.zoneball.BallHoldActivity.onCreate(BallHoldActivity.java:17)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     ... 11 more
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     ... 25 more
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     at oaa.tms.zoneball.ballHold.BallHoldView.<init>(BallHoldView.java:37)
10-05 17:44:04.336: E/AndroidRuntime(3474):     ... 28 more
```

EDIT:
Using the following code I have confirmed scoreText is null:

```
scoreText = (TextView)((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
            Log.e("BallHoldView", "scoreText created");
    if(scoreText != null)
    {
        scoreText.setText("New Score");
            Log.e("BallHoldView", "scoreText changed");
    }
    else
        Log.e("BallHoldView", "scoreText was null");
```

Why is it null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code at line # 37

```
scoreText.setText("New Score");
```

`scoreText` is `null`.

```
scoreText = (TextView)((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
```

The above line is not able to find the `scoreText`. This might be because when the custom view layout is inflated, it will call its constructor, and in there you are trying to refer `scoreText` which has not been inflated yet, as it comes after `ballHold` in your android xml.
The solution might be to put the `ballHold` custom view after your `scoreText` in android xml. Or otherwise the proper way would be to pass the `scoreText` TextView from your java activity code to the `BallHoldView` CustomView class in its constructor and then use it. In that case, in your activity code you will definitely be able to find view by id.

Comment: snap! you're quick :-)
Thank you, I will try both ways. (one at a time!)

Comment: I have not been able to get either method to work. It seems there is a great deal of trouble online for people to pass TextView components from activity xml through to custom views. I think I will have to remove scoreText from the activity code and keep it purely with the custom view code.

Comment: Removed `scoreText` from the xml and created it programatically from within the custom view.